# LFTP - Remove files from remote server while uploading via lftp mirror --reverse

Tags: performance, ftp, lftp

I'm using a shell script which executes `lftp mirror --reverse` to upload files and directories to a remote server. Just before that it removes everything using `glob -a rm -r -f *`. The problem is, it is not so fast. Whole operation takes couple of minutes, especially the recursive removal. I'm uploading few megabytes of data in a couple of hundred files, but most of them do not change. I'm connecting through FTPS protocol.

#### Question

How to improve the performance of my script?

I was thinking about uploading only files that are new or were changed locally and at the same time removing the ones from the remote server that are not present on my local machine. Sadly, I don't know if it is possible or how to achieve it.

**Whole script:**

```
lftp $host << EOF

user $username $password
cd $destination_directory
glob -a rm -r -f *
mirror --reverse $local_directory .
exit

EOF
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution was at hand. While digging through LFTP manual I found that `mirror` command has a `--delete` option which perfectly suits my needs.

> `--delete`
>
> delete files not present at the source ~ [LFTP Manual](https://lftp.yar.ru/lftp-man.html)

I changed

```
glob -a rm -r -f *
mirror --reverse $local_directory .
```

to

```
mirror --reverse --delete $local_directory .
```